# How to draw a line in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, blazor, webassembly

Literally how to draw a line in Blazor? I have seen [this project](https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Canvas) on GitHub and it is a wrapper of HTML canvas and I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169450/how-do-i-access-the-html-canvas-from-blazor), and [this article](https://dev.to/azure/creating-dev-s-offline-page-using-blazor-29dl) among others and they seem to make calls through JavaScript to draw on a canvas so it basically executes as plain JS code.

I wonder if there is another way to draw line and create animations like in Blazor that should have close to native performance.

Is there an alternative to HTML canvas and keep wrapping JS calls in order to create draw lines like animations, like something official that supports this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no currently no alternative and nothing is build into Blazor for this.

Blazor uses web technologies to render the user interface.

Even if Blazor would offer a build-in way to draw stuff that would be nothing else than an opininated API over canvas or WebGL.

Nevertheless, I hope that the team will one day decide to create such an in build-in API for drawing on the canvas. Those drawing capabilities will make Blazor even more attractive for a lot of users. Take a look at the huge success of p5js and the amount of new programmers that p5js has brought to the javascript community.

I think the chance that Blazor team will take up such a task is pretty low, they probably hope the community will do it. However, the chances to get a great Windows Graphic Rendering Library from MS was pretty low as well and we got Shawn Hargreaves creating the awesome Win2D library.  So let's keep the finger crossed!

Comment: I really hope that one day somebody will edit this answer saying that there is another way, that MS or even the community built a graphics API integrated in Blazor, but until then, we will use what we have.

Comment: This is a fundamental limitation of the WebAssembly technology. WebAssembly doesn't have an API for this, so that means JavaScript is needed. No matter what abstraction you're given, the end result will be JavaScript based until WebAssembly is given an API with direct access. This is not a "Blazor issue".

Comment: @EdCharbeneau Are you sure that WASM cannot render on the page? I'm looking into [Skia CanvasKit](https://skia.org/docs/user/modules/canvaskit/) and it looks promising.

Comment: @Amir "WebGL context encapsulated as an SkSurface, allowing for direct drawing to an HTML canvas". WebGL is a JavaScript API, therefore... "No matter what abstraction you're given, the end result is JavaScript"

Answer (score 1):

By draw, do you mean the user can create lines interactively?  Or just that you want to programmatically add content to the screen.  Because these are very different issues.

If it's the latter, then you should consider inline `<svg>`, which has 2 advantages: 1) svg lines aren't pixellated, so they can scale and always look great; 2) `<svg>` tags, being markup, can be added directly in Blazor.

EVEN IF I were drawing lines interactively, I'd choose `svg` over an HTML Canvas, tbh, unless I was trying to make an interface for SD or something.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround from January 2023. No way from Blazor, you must use JavaScript :_(

In the .razor file

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("TestCanvas", "myCanvas");
    }
}
```

In `TestCanvas.js` file

```
function TestCanvas(id) {
    let canvas = document.getElementById(id);

    if (canvas == null) {
        return false;
    }

    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
}
```

Add a reference to the TestCanvas.js file in "_Layout.html"

```
<script src="~/js/TestCanvas.js"></script>
```